# Changing Touch Bar Icons

Tags: icon, siri, customization, touch-bar

I want to have the Siri icon in the Touch Bar, but I want to change the icon to a black and white version. I find the colors distracting, and I want it to be visually consistent with all of the other icons.

Is there any way to change the icons for a given touch bar item?

Comment: It looks like this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41110454/macos-sierra-touch-bar-icons-location

Comment: Better touch tool may be able to do this